# CPU usage/utilization calculation from traces

Tags: cpu-usage, gem5

I'm trying to determine the CPU usage/utilization from a set of traces (part of an executed program). Calculating cpu cycles without considering pipelining is fine, as the different operation latencies are known. The program is executed with pipelining, which makes this calculation difficult. I have the overall CPU usage of the program, but I'd like to manually calculate it for a time interval of the program. Underneath is a snip of the traces, first column being the tick count, second column the operation, third the operation type and fourth being the addresses. Lets say I wanted to calcute the CPU usage for the first 25 rows, would anyone have some tips or tricks on how I could do this?

Thanks in advance

[image: Snip of traces]

Comment: Hi Øivind, I don't have an amazing answer for this (as usual? :-)) but I don't think you can calculate that from `Exec` traces alone (unless you are a Timing analysis God?). One thing I'd have a look at for O3 at least is: http://www.m5sim.org/Visualization which uses `--debug-flags=O3PipeView`. It feels like what you want could be extracted from there maybe for O3 at least. Also one recommendation: on Stack Overflow, always post plaintext code blocks rather than screenshots of text :-)

Comment: Hi Ciro, thanks a lot for the help yet again. Always very much appriciated :) Sorry for the late reply, I've been trying to figure out different approaches too. I'm bound to using an in-order CPU which makes the O3PipeView debug flag not applicable (actually tried to set it, just to see). Tried to set a bunch of different debug flags too, to see if I can use any of it for timing analysis, but without luck. I'll have to see how I can solve this. But as always, really appriciate your time and efforts. Thanks for the heads up regarding screenshots too, I'll keep that in mind from now on:)

Comment: Cool! If you don't find a way, consider adding a new log that does what you want to Minor and sending a patch, I'm sure it would be useful to other people.